# Android ContentProvider - UPDATE with bitwise operations

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I just figured out that I'm not able to use `SQLiteDatabase.update()` method to update column via bitwise operations:

```
ContentValues.put(Contract.ProductColumns.LOCAL_TYPE, Contract.ProductColumns.LOCAL_TYPE + "|" + 8);
getContentResolver().update(URI, ContentValues, null, null);
```

invokes: `SQLiteDatabase.update(tableName, values, selection, selectionArgs)`
inside `ContentProvider.update()` and it seems it runs something like:

```
UPDATE products SET product_local_type = "local_type|8";
```

instead of this:

```
UPDATE products SET product_local_type = local_type|8;
```

How can i achieve such update command? (without parenthesis)

Comment: Is this a custom ContentProvider that you can modify?  In order to get the update semantics you want, you will need to run a sql raw query.

Comment: Yes it is custom ContentProvider. Raw query was only solution that came in my mind too. Would you do it that way if you want to work with flags?